# Are there an infinite number of integers $n$ such that $n, n+1$, and $n+2$ have the same number of divisors?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

Is the set $S:=\{n\in\mathbb{N} \mid \text{$n$, $n+1$ and $n+2$ have the same number of divisors}\}$ infinite?

Example: $33\in S$.

Comment: The answer is surely yes, even for triples $(3p,2q,5r)$ with prime $p,q,r$. Another question is how to prove.

Comment: Please use LaTeX for mathematical notation.

Comment: @Fedor: why are you sure?

Comment: Heath-Brown proved that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $n$ and $n+1$ have the same number of divisors.  It is conjectured that your statement is true.  See Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* Problem B18.  Indeed, there it is conjectured that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n, n+1, n+2$ are all the product of two primes (this is stronger than your conjecture and weaker than Fedor's).

Comment: It is a very special case of widely believed (I think, cause of probabilistic heuristics) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture

Comment: @Fedor Petrov- I think (3p, 2q, 5r) is not a unique set. (33, 34, 35), (85, 86, 87), and (93, 94, 95) conform to the above set. However, set (141, 142, 143) does not conform.

Comment: @MathivananPalraj of course there are many other examples. For example, triples $(17p,2q,3r)$.

Answer (score 8):

I will convert my comment into an answer, since I suspect it is still the state of the art.

The version of your question for two consecutive integers was proved in

> Heath-Brown, D. R. (1984). *The divisor function at consecutive integers.* Mathematika, 31(01), 141-149.
>   ISO 690

See this [paper](http://msp.org/pjm/1987/129-2/pjm-v129-n2-p06-s.pdf) of Hildebrand (the Heath-Brown paper is behind a paywall) for an improvement of Heath-Brown's result.

As Fedor Petrov mentions, your conjecture is very likely true, but is still an open problem (as far as I know).  Indeed, your conjecture appears explicitly in Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* (Section 18B).  This section also contains a lot of other related conjectures and results.  For example, Erdős conjectured that for any $k$, there exist $k$ consecutive integers with the same number of divisors.